# Result of expression '$.mobile' [undefined] is not an object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, local-storage

I'm new in jquery mobile,and i develop a mobile application with jquery mobile and phoneGap and localstorage Html , i want to save an input value in page.html and then i will then retrieve this value withlocalstorage.getitem and used in a URL, My problem when I add this line  `value=localStorage.getItem('myStorage');` I can not connect to my app and I got this error :

> Result of expression '$.mobile' [undefined] is not an object. at
>   file:///android_asset/www/js/application.js:258

this is my application of saving the input value
application.js

```
function setMessage() {
    var firstName=document.getElementById('addresseip');
    alert("Hello " + firstName.value + ", hope you like JavaScript functions!")

                    localStorage.setItem('myStorage', firstName.value);

}
```

and this is my call to this value in the same page .js, the input vaule is an param.html and the call to this value is in index.html :

```
function showUser(){
 value=localStorage.getItem('myStorage');
val1 = document.getElementById("name").value;
val2 = document.getElementById("pass").value;

if (val1=="")
  {
   showdialog("Verifiez login et mot de passe","Erreur");
  } 
  else{
     alert("test"+value);    
  $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();    
   var geturl;
  geturl = $.ajax({  

   url:"https://"+value+":80/B/authenticate",  
   //url:"https://10.0.2.2:80/B/authenticate",  
   dataType:"json",
   timeout:10000000,  
   cache:false,
   type:'GET',
   beforeSend : function(req) {
             req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 
                   make_base_auth (val1, val2));
        },
   error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) { 
   $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
   showdialog("Verifiez login et mot de passe","Erreur"); 
   },   
   success:function(results) { 
   if(results==true){

    $.mobile.changePage("bienvenu.html","fade");
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();  
   }
```

My error is an line  $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

Can you please help me, 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except loading jQuery you should also include jQM. Make sure also that your code that uses jQM is included after it.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="yourscripts.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    /* Your code here */
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `$.mobile` is `undefined`, I guess that the jquery mobile library is not loaded. Check that you have loaded jquery and jquery mobile before calling `showUser()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response , but i don't understing how i load jquery and jquery mobile, in my include like this  `<script type="text/javascript" src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">` , or i must use another method

Comment: This line loads jquery. For jquery mobile, you'll find the answer in the doc, see e.g.: http://jquerymobile.com/ > Docs > Quick start guide.